# Getting Header as a response of API

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, rest

I'am using a REST API which returns some JSON block as a response.Here my request fulfills successfully but it returns some header block as a response instead of JSON. What does this code block means ?
P.S : I'm using NSURLSessionDataTask for hitting API.

```
        { 
            status code: 200, headers {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" = true;
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "origin, content-type, accept, authorization";
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT";
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
            "Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
            Date = "Thu, 08 Sep 2016 08:19:00 GMT";
            Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
            "Transfer-Encoding" = Id 

        }
```

Comment: Why do you print the `NSHTTPURLResponse`? It's the info that were in the HTTP Response. Read the `NSData` var of the completion block.

Comment: Thankyou , i got your point.

Answer (score 0):

header properties are your servis properties. for example;

Access-Control-Allow-Methods -> Which can call Methods. You can call get, post, delete and put function or services in your services project.

Content-Type -> Services return object type.

I hope that helps.